# Problemas com $.get e PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Gelera estou me batendo um pouco apra descobrir o que está acontecendo com um código que montei.
Tenho um loop que baixa arquivos `.csv` de um servidor especifico para o meu servidor. São 9 arquivos.
Após termino dos downloads preciso apagar as bases, realizar as inserções novamente e apagar os arquivos, parecia simples mas algumas coisas estão saindo do controle.

No inicio o arquivo "insert_delete.php" recebia os 3 loops dos 9 arquivos, porém ele se perdia e registrava logs informando duplicata de inserções e delete de arquivos. Sendo assim separei em 3 arquivos, isso parou de acontecer.

Um questão estranha é que quando executo diretamente o arquivo "insert_delete.php" tudo acontece dentro dos conformes, porém quando executo pelo `script` a base está ficando em branco, como se o `TRUNCATE` acontecesse depois do `foreach`.

Me parece que está passando algo e não estou vendo.

Vamos lá a bagunça que eu fiz:

**Script**

```
//Contagem dos arquivos se houver mais que 8 arquivos realiza a solicitação de inserção, se não continua contando
function cont(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.get("query/cont_arquivos.php", function( data ) {
            if(data < 9){
                $('.box_loading').show();
                $(".cont").html(
                    "Aguardando arquivos "+data
                );
                cont();
            }else{
                $.get("insert_delete.php", function(){});
                $.get("insert_delete1.php", function(){
                    $('.box_loading').hide();
                });
                $.get("insert_delete2.php", function(){});

                $(".cont").html(
                    "Inserindo nas bases... "
                );
            }
        });

    },1000);
}
```

**PHP(insert delete)**

```
<?php
include "conn.php";

$files1 = glob('nomedosarquivos*.csv'); // obten alguns arquivos da pasta

$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE nomedatabela"; //apaga a base
$conn->query($sql);

if(count($files1)>2){
  foreach($files1 as $file){ // loop dos 3 arquivos
    if(is_file($file))
    if (($base = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $count = 0;
        $ok = 0;
        $erro = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($base, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
            $count++; //contar as linhas
            if ($count == 1) { continue; } //não inserir os titulos

            if ($data[0] == "") { break; } //sai do while se este campo estiver em branco

            //validações de campos

            $sql = "INSERT into nomedatabela (campos....) VALUES (dados..)";
            if($conn->query($sql)==TRUE){
                $ok++;
                //somente conta as linhas que foram inseridas

            }else{
                //conta os erros
                $erro++;
                //executa o log informando qual erro e em qual linha aconteceu
            }
        }
        fclose ($base);
        if(unlink($file)){
            //executa o log informando que o arquivo foi deletado
        }else{
            //executa o log informando um erro ao deletar o arquivo
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Você está usado chamadas ajax ($.get) assíncronas esperando que ele execute no servidor de forma síncrona. Tente encadear as chamadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você ja tentou utilizar o $.get().done().always().fail()?

Pelo que eu vi, esses métodos teriam que ser chamados após o término do anterior ....

```
  function cont() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.get("query/cont_arquivos.php", function (data) {
            if (data < 9) {
                $('.box_loading').show();
                $(".cont").html(
                    "Aguardando arquivos " + data
                );
                cont();
            } else {
                $.get("insert_delete.php", function () { })
                .done(function () {
                    $.get("insert_delete1.php", function () {
                        $('.box_loading').hide();
                    }).done(function () {
                        $.get("insert_delete2.php", function () {
                        }).done(function () {
                            $(".cont").html("Inserindo nas bases... ");
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Acho que era isso mesmo, me parece que do modo que eu estava realizando o $.get ocorria mais de uma solicitação ao arquivo, resolvido. Muito Obrigado.